# Which machine learning approach should I use to remember a sequence of natural numbers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, lstm

I need to train a model such that it remembers a sequence of natural numbers, e.g., 1-100(1 2 3 .. 99 100) and when tested with an input sequence such as 1 2 3 ...74 75 32 76 77... 99 100 101, it should point out both the anomalies i.e., 32 and 101.

NOTE : **The above example has 100 unique keys i.e. 1 to 100**.

The actual model which I plan to train has an input for around 10k natural numbers(**around 300 unique keys repeated in different sequence**) and the testing will also be similar to what I mentioned in the above example with multiple numbers out of sequence in the test file.

I'm new to the concepts of machine learning and having a difficult time figuring this out. Is there any approach to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to use machine learning, when you can compare every number with the number preceding it and solve the problem ?

Comment: The sequence which I need to train is non-linear like 1-100 as shown in the example, but it is machine-generated and has a pattern to it. I need to find any anomalies in the test pattern by training with the actual pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using an RNN. This is a recurrent neural network. It backpropogates through time while training. It does amazing with sequences. You can take it better with LSTMs(long short term memory networks) or bidirectional layers in your model.

- check out this tutorial to get you started with these kind of models
  quickly : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn

If you're new to Machine learning and cant understand this, Thats ok. I didn't either. But copy and paste the code play around with the hypermeters of the model. The best way to learn is by doing. But make sure that after you've done this, get a firm understanding how LSTMs work. If you dont know how neural nets work or any other machine learning techniques work ,I'd recommend learning them now. A good place to get started is with linear regression. I understood how it worked by making a notebook where I wrote all the math and I learnt the whole thing from this statistics tutorial:

- http://onlinestatbook.com/2/regression/intro.html

Thats all I got. If you dont understand anything still get in touch with me. I think there is a way to DM on stackoverflow. If not edit ur question or better, comment on my answer and I'll edit it. :)

post ur notebook maybe I can help?

good bye for now and happy coding :)